# Compiler Error while Overloading - Java

Tags: java

```
class parent
{
    public void disp(int i)
    {
        System.out.println("int");
    }
}

class child extends parent
{
    private void disp(long l)
    {
        System.out.println("long");
    }
}

class impl
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        child c = new child();
        c.disp(0l); //Line 1
    }
}
```

Compiler complains as below

```
inh6.java:27: error: disp(long) has private access in child
c.disp(0l);
```

The input given is 0L and I am trying to overload the disp() method in child class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `disp()` is declared as private

```
private void disp(long l){System.out.println("long");}
```

As such, it is only visible within the `child` class, not from the `impl` class where you are trying to call it. Either change its visibility to `public` or rethink your design.

If your question is why is it seeing the `disp(long)` instead of `disp(int)`, this is because you provided a `long` primitive value to the method call.

```
 c.disp(0l); // the 'l' at the end means 'long'
```

The official tutorial for access modifiers is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: "not from the impl class where you are trying to call "...Thanks for pointing this :)